# What is the usage of id property of @KafkaClient

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, micronaut

I am new in Kafka and microservices. I tried to understand the usage of id property of @KafkaClient but most of the examples are given without that property therefore could not understand clearly.

```
@KafkaClient(id = "client_id")
```

What is the usage of id property in that case? What does it mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If it's not provided, a default name is generated, which is why the examples don't show it.  It's just an identifier of that consumer instance. So if you wanted to have a consumer named "Delayed-Consumer#1" you could use that, instead of a default that might be Consumer#1.

Comment: In which case do I need to know name of consumer or producer ?Is there a such a situation? As I understand they are interested in related message topics.

Comment: Logs, mainly, from my experience. But there might be some plugin modules or apis that can use that field.